# How can I install packages from the Arch Linux installation USB into my installed Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, system-installation

I've just finished installing Arch Linux [following this guide](https://www.linuxtechi.com/dual-boot-arch-linux-windows-10/).

I was having some trouble and now, although Arch is installed, I do not have `iw` or `wireless_tools` packages installed. I do not have an ethernet connection, so now I'm unable to setup my wifi connection because I can't download the needed packages.

I know the packages must be on the installation USB, because I was able to run `iwctl` during the installation process to get everything going.

So how can I install the packages from the installation USB into my install of Arch?

Comment: If you have a modern smartphone you can easily use a temporary connection, USB tethering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChanganAuto mentioned, you can use USB tethering with your mobile phone on data.

Also as per [docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Install_essential_packages), you can

> use `pacman` to install them while chrooted into the new system

It won't install the package from the USB per se, but use the installation media that has Wi-Fi configured to let you connect by Wi-Fi and install the network package you need for your Arch install.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to mount your installed Arch Linux to `/mnt`.
- Then type `pacstrap /mnt (your packages)`
- Then unmount your installed Arch Linux from `/mnt` and reboot to your installed Arch Linux.